# How to import external static JS files into NuxtJS3 globally

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am using NuxtJS in 3.6.1 version and I want to include my static JS files which are responsible for DOM interaction.

I tried this approach but without any luck.

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    devtools: { enabled: true },
    css: ['@/assets/scss/app.scss', '@/assets/scss/icons.scss'],
    app: {
        head: {
            script: [
                {
                    type: 'text/javascript',
                    src: 'js/layout.js',
                },
            ],
        },
    },
})
```

I attempted to include CSS files within a link block within the head section, but the CSS appears to be ignored. However, when I place the CSS files next to the app, they work correctly. It seems that everything within the app is being disregarded, but I'm unsure of the reason behind this behavior. I've attempted using the "public" folder as well as "static" and "assets" folders, but the issue persists.